# How to click on static text in applescript

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bCVw.png)

I have the window of the picture above, save the configuration through stand-alone save, AppleScript can not click Save through click, the following script returns missing value, please ask in AppleScript, how to click static text

````
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "WeChat"
                click menu item "Proxy Settings..." of menu "WeChat" of menu bar 1
                click radio button "Don't Use" of window "Proxy Settings"
                delay 1
                set focused to true
                click static text "Save" of window "Proxy Settings"
        end tell
end tell
```[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWJ9V.png)
````

tell application "System Events"
tell process "WeChat"
click menu item "Proxy Settings..." of menu "WeChat" of menu bar 1
click radio button "Don't Use" of window "Proxy Settings"
delay 1
set focused to true
click static text "Save" of window "Proxy Settings"
end tell
end tell

Answer (score 0):

I don't have/use WeChat, so cannot examine the UI to confirm here, but `static text` elements—generally speaking—don't often have `actions` attached to them (`"AXPress"` is the name of the `action` that the **`click`** command aliases).  From a design perspective, `static text` elements are intended as an inert label for some other `UI element` that plays a functional role.  In this case, it looks like a `button` element, and its name is probably also `"Save"`.  `button` elements are also good candidates for attaching a whole bunch of `actions` to.

Therefore, instead of:

```
click static text "Save" of window "Proxy Settings"
```

you could try:

```
click button "Save" of window "Proxy Settings"
```

If that throws an error, it'll either be because the `button` element's name is not `"Save"`, or the element is not a `button`.  But you can find out what it is like this:

```
-- click button "Save" of window "Proxy Settings"
tell window "Proxy Settings" to get (the last UI element ¬
         where the name of its actions contains "AXPress")
```

This will yield a reference to the object you're trying to click, by virtue of its `actions` necessarily containing one named *"AXPress"* (i.e. it responds to the **`click`** command), and its physical positioning almost certainly inferring it to be the last such `UI element`.

Answer (score 0):

"Save" is not a button, and only one button can be found through the UI element, this button is a close button, and nothing else.